# primary keys continue adding id numbers like deleted items here

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

when i create a new table in mysql(phpmyadmin) in one column like

```
 id TEXT auto_increment primarykey
```

so when i began adding items table id column goes 1 2 3 4 5 ..... Okay, no problem so far.

lets say in my table i have id's 1 to 45. and let's say i deleted id's 41, 42, 43, 44 and 45.and after that i add another item to table. id's start from 46 but i want them continue like 41 42 43 .... again.

Is there an options section for that in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Why using "auto_incement" if you don't want it like it is? you may omit "auto_incement" in the creation and use a select max(id) + 1 from ... to obtain the last id for inserting a new item. But what if you delete the the id's 2, 4, 6, 8?

Comment: In this case the `id` (identity) column is a *surrogate key*, it should serve *no other purpose* then uniquely identifying a row.  If you need it to meet other criteria, you are generally doing something wrong.  In some distributed databases, Teradata for example, you have *no idea* what the 'next' value will ever be, and you should never need to, only that the value is unique.  Perhaps if you can explain why you *want* all the values to be sequential, we can advise on a different pattern to fulfill your functional requirements.  But this is extremely unlikely to be it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't how auto_increment works. You can reset the auto_increment pointer in MySQL though, which might give you want you want, depending on your use-cases.

See [set auto increment initial value for mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557856/set-auto-increment-initial-value-for-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, I've seen that in other RDBMSs too.

This is by design, I don't think you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a command to reseed the identity field:

```
alter table mytable auto_increment=41;
```

however, there really isn't much point in doing this. Numeric keys are just that - they don't need to be contiguous.