# how to auto-increment a value in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm new to php and when I add data in my table, the item_id will be  **AUTO INCREMENT** and it must start at **00000001**   what php function will I use ?

```
item_Id | item_description
00000001| Samsung galaxy s3
```

and when I add another item it will be something like this:

```
 item_Id | item_description
 00000001| Samsung galaxy s3
 00000002| Remote Controller
```

I'm using codeigniter.

Comment: It's more about how you set up your MySQL database, set the `item_Id` column to primary key with auto_increment

Comment: how am i going to set the item_id starting with "00000001" ? sorry i'm new in php

Comment: this might help to set custom auto_increment :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: perhaps you can get answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557856/set-auto-increment-initial-value-for-mysql-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do auto-incrementing in the database, when you define the table:

```
create table items (
    item_id unsigned not null auto_increment,
    . . .
);
```

When you insert an item, just insert all other columns besides the `item_id`:

```
insert into items(col1, . . . )
    . . .
```

The database will set the `item_id` to a new value whenever new values are inserted.

Note:  the inserted value is an integer.  If you want to pull it out as a zero-padded string, you can do:

```
SELECT LPAD(item_id, 8, '0')
```

Comment: when i set the item_id it will be like this? item_id unsigned not null auto_increment = "00000001", ?

Comment: @Vincent . . . The initial value is 1, so you don't need to set it.  And, the leading zeros are useless, because the column is numeric.  You can put them in when you query the value.

Comment: but i need the other seven zeros, i will show it in my other html pages

Comment: That is why I have the "Note".  You can pull it out with the leading zeroes by using `lpad()`.  If you think about it, you cannot "increment" a string value.  But, you can increment a number and turn it into a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I haven't used ZEROFILL in conjunction with PHP, but wouldn't `item_id INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT;` work for capturing it as a padded value in PHP? EDIT: Wow, old thread. Not sure how / why this popped up on recent questions.

Answer (score -1):

since it's an item ID and not used in calculations just use VARCHAR and format the number to add leading zeros and convert to string
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php